# Delete item from array , why for and for in output are different?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, for-in-loop

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c",null,undefined];

delete arr[0];

for (var i = 0,j=arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    /*
    undefined
    b
    c
    null
    undefined
    */
}

for (var o in arr) {
    console.log(arr[o]);
    /*
    b
    c
    null
    undefined
    */
}
```

who can tell me why the output is different?

Comment: `for-in` is for property enumeration. You've deleted the `0` property, so there's nothing there to enumerate. `for-in` is usually the wrong approach for an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have access by key;

array index is key of array object

using delete keyword, remove object key 
because

```
delete arr[0]; // key "0" deleted!
```

ok?

and see this

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c",null,undefined];
delete arr[0]; // key "0" deleted!

// access by i,  with key : 0
for (var i = 0,j=arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    /*
    0 
    1 
    2 
    3 
    4 
    */
}

// access by object key, without key : 0
for (var o in arr) {
    console.log(o);
    /*
    1
    2
    3
    4 
    */
}​​​​​​​​​​
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually `delete` doesn't remove the element from the array it only sets the element as undefined, to remove an item from an array use `splice` as follows

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c",null,undefined];
arr.splice(0, 1);
```

Now your array is as follows

```
["b", "c", null, undefined]
```

But you used `delete` to remove the first item from the array as follows

```
delete arr[0];
```

and after that your array looked like as follows

```
[undefined × 1, "b", "c", null, undefined]
```

So, In your first loop you used

```
for (var i = 0,j=arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

It iterated array using index of the array so (in the loop for the the first time) `arr[i]` means `arr[0]` which is `undefined` and in your second loop you used

```
for (var o in arr) {
    console.log(arr[o]);
}
```

This is actually ideal to use with an object to loop but you used an array ,well I think it should also display other properties of the array and really confused how did you get only these `(b c null undefined)` values unless you use `hasOwnProperty`

```
for (var o in arr) {
    if(arr.hasOwnProperty(o)) console.log(arr[o]);
}
```

Whatever, it iterates all available properties of an object and should not be used with an array. Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/GdJzA/) to understand how `hasOwnProperty` works and what you should get without using this method when iterating an `array` using `for in`.

Answer (score 0):

Given an empty array `array = []`, `array[0]` returns `undefined`, becase there is no item stored in position 0. After deleting `arr[0]`, there is no data there. Loop with `for .. in ..` iterate all elements in array, so it returns `b c null undefined`. More specific, `for .. in ..` loops properties in an object. So, if you assign a new property, say `name` to `arr`, `arr.name = "an array"`, it shall be printed in `for .. in ..` loop.